# calculating confidence interval when sample has many zeros

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to calculate confidence interval of a sample output but the sample output per user can have either a 0 - 50 but when I calculate confidence interval using below it gives me a CI with low values, is there a way to normalize for this or would that be the correct CI?

I cannot paste the list as it has 250K values

```
import scipy.stats as st
st.norm.interval(confidence=0.95, loc=np.mean(x), scale=st.sem(x))




**(0.02455443693126938, 0.026450854074021625)**
```

Comment: First of all, why are you using `sem` instead of `std`? Moreover, it's a good idea to plot the histogram and see how your data looks like.

Comment: `the sample output per user can have either a 0 - 50` do you mean you have binomial distribution?

Answer (score 0):

The confidence interval should be based on the standard deviation instead of standard error of the sample. Your result changes drastically. Check the difference:

```
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.stats import norm
r = norm.rvs(loc=25, scale=12, size=1000)
import numpy as np
```

Using standard error of the mean:

```
st.norm.interval(confidence=0.95, loc=np.mean(r), scale=st.sem(r))
```

Output:

```
(23.894125988443633, 25.37912976058209)
```

Using standard deviation:

```
st.norm.interval(confidence=0.95, loc=np.mean(r), scale=np.std(r))
```

Output:

```
(1.1683995271163887, 48.10485622190933)
```

Comment: weird this method is giving me a dif output then what I am expecting

Comment: You may get slightly different results due to randomness of the generated data, unless we set the initial seed. Could you please report the mean, standard deviation, and sample size of your data?